# Django-CMS unsuccessful while removing plugin from page

Tags: sql, django, django-cms

I can add successfuly plugin to page with created by django cms. But, when I try to remove plugin from page  plug in don't disappears and I got this execption error:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/cms/page/3/remove-plugin/

relation "cmsplugin_latestentriesplugin" does not exist
LINE 1: ...latestentriesplugin"."current_language_only" FROM "cmsplugin...
                                                             ^

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://example.com/admin/cms/page/3/remove-plugin/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     DatabaseError
Exception Value:    

relation "cmsplugin_latestentriesplugin" does not exist
LINE 1: ...latestentriesplugin"."current_language_only" FROM "cmsplugin...

                                                         ^
```

How can I correct this error?

Comment: Are you using `zinnia` blog? If so what version & also what version of django? It might be a problem with zinnia if you are https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/pull/70

Comment: I was added cmsplugin_blog but It cause some problems, so I removed from INSTALLED_APPS for now to deal with it in beyond. Not using blog plug in right now.

Comment: so are you using `cmsplugin_latestentriesplugin` or just trying to remove is completely?

Comment: No, I did not add `cmsplugin_latestentriesplugin` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figure out that, I missed to remove `cmsplugin_blog.middleware.MultilingualBlogEntriesMiddleware` from settings.

It's now works fine.

Comment: If I launch the migrate command I have your problem. 
Plus this error:
No registered apphook `BlogApphook` found.
Exception Location: /srv/virtualenvs/fm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/apphook_pool.py in get_apphook, line 70

I suppose it's linked to: https://github.com/Fantomas42/cmsplugin-zinnia/issues/12